# get a float number from a void*

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

I'm trying to re-program the printf function (college project) but the %f is causing me problems.
I use function pointers like so :

```
void (*fct[15])(void*) =
            {printfs, printfc, printfd, printfd, printfl, printfx, printfX,
             printfo, printfb, printfS, printfu, printfp, printff};
```

when the right flag is used, one of these function is called.
A typical printfd will recieves a void* variable as parameter and will do so :

```
int nbr = (int)var;     //var is a void* type variable
my_put_nbr(var);        //handmade function wich displays numbers
```

The thing is, for some odd reason, when i did the same for printff, it didn't work

```
float nbr = (float)var;
```

I get the message

> error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
>   float nbr = (float)var

I also tried to to something like this. If i have

```
my_printf("%f", var);     //with var = 12.34
```

Then i call the function printff() which should do :

```
int nbr1 = (int)(var / 1);
int nbr2 = (int)(var % 1);
```

So i'd have normally nbr1 = 12 and nbr2 = 34 i would then display both with in between a '.' But it still doesn't work and i get the message :

> error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘void *’ and ‘int’) int nbr1
>   = (int)(var*1)

I'm out of ideer so if you have any clue, tell me.
Also, i cannot use commands like printf() or something, that's the rule of this exercise so don't tell me the solution hides here.

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] because there really isn't enough code shown so far to have any idea what you're doing. Although at a guess, it looks like you should research variable argument lists.

Comment: You are trying to case a pointer to a normal value!

Comment: `(int)var` will not work as expected either, it will  get you the integer representation of the address pointed by `var`, not the integer value stored at that location. **You simply cannot cast between pointer types and value types.** What you can do is cast a `void*` to a `int*`, and then dereference it: `int x = *(int*)var;`.

Comment: "one of these function is called" show the call.

Comment: By the way a printf-like function can **never** get a float, ever. Only a double. Note in the standard library printf, `%f` expects a double argument. There is no output format specification for floats, have you ever wondered why?

Comment: Indeed. Check out _the default argument promotions_ of a va function's parameters.

Comment: Trying again. How `fct[i]` are called? Show the code.

Comment: Groo it still works anyway. I can do a (int)var and it perfectly works, i've tested it. I understand why it shouldn't but it still works so i'll continue to use it. I've tried to use it to solve my problem float nbr = *(float*)var; but i just get nbr = 0.0 and it does the same with a double type. Though, i don't get any error nor warnings

Comment: it's too long to write it in comment so i'll just tell you how it works. I scan the string "%f" to find a '%' character. If i do, i'll check the character next to it. I'll then scan another string flag[] = "scidlxXobSupfeE" with all flags i've coded. The number of the corresponding box matches the function pointer ('f' would call printff() or 'd' would call printfd() ) so we call it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  you just do not know the language - you even do not understand the difference between the pointer to the object and the object itself. You need a good C beginners book first.

Comment: don't try pasting your code in a comment - edit your question!

Comment: PeterJ_01 or you could calm down and ask questions cause i've given the strict minimum info since it's a project i've made in 2 or 3 weeks (so too long to explain everything) and cause you might not understand everything and believe it's off topic... If i ask a question this particular, you should rather try to answer it rather than closing it

Comment: Chris, it's long, complex, i'm using stdarg lib so the 50 lines of programs i use to call a function would be too long and too complex to write down in comment or in the question itself. It's doesn't really matter how i call it ( just know that it is this way fct[j](va_arg(args, void*)); ) since i gave you all you needed to answer the problem. It would get off topic if you tried to understand how i call it, since the problem isn't here. I get a void* which was a float (works with int, char ect...) that's it

Comment: *"I understand why it shouldn't but it still works so i'll continue to use it"* - yeah, that's a rather problematic approach to pretty much anything, not just programming. Just add `#define float int` somewhere and your work is done.

Comment: Here is a snippet from your program which "perfectly works", which you've "tested" and will "continue to use": https://ideone.com/3Z2gJG. Check the `stdout` at the bottom and tell me why the number isn't 5.

Comment: Your use of va_arg is incorrect and leads to undefined behaviour. You have to redesign your entire approach. The fact that it appears to work for a single `int` argument on your computer is a pure accident, and an unfortunate one because it caused you to wasre so much time on a dead end approach.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly, when you are entirely sure of the caller part, in the called function, considering you receive the argument in `var`, you can do

- For `int`

  ```
  printf("%d", *(int *)var);
  ```
- For `float`/ `double`

  ```
  printf("%f", *(double *)var);
  ```

and so on.

Please note, there exist no `float` type for variadic functions, because, for those functions, due to default argument promotion, `float` types get promoted to `double`.

To elaborate, you do not cast / assign the incoming pointer to the required type (that is both invalid [type mismatch] and unwanted). Rather, you cast the `void *` parameter to the appropriate caller argument type, (based on flag, you mentioned) and then, dereference that to obtain the value.

This analogy is based on the property mentioned in `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to
>   any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall
>   compare equal to the original pointer.

Comment: i'd love to do that but i'm not the one using the function, really. We have a computer which test our programs so the way my_printf() is called must match the way we usually call printf(). That means i must write my_printf("%d", nbr); and not my_printf("%d", (int)nbr);

Comment: This answer would benefit from mentioning that variadic `float` arguments get promoted to `double`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck If you think it's useful, let me add, it does no harm, after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is called punning. Pointer punning is the UB. The safest way is to memcpy the data from the void pointer to the float variable.

`float x;
memcpy (&x, voidptr, sizeof(float));`

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling `va_args` correctly. The second parameter has to be the data type you're expecting to read from the variable parameters because `va_args` needs the correct size to know where to get the next parameter from.

Whilst your use of an array to store all the possibly functions might appear to be clever, you're actually making things harder for yourself when there is an easier and much more readable way to do it. It's probably also a lot more expandable too.

```
switch(format_char)
  {
case 'd':
  print_an_int(va_args(args,int));
break;
case 'f':
  print_an_float(va_args(args,float));
break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
int nbr = *((int *)var); 
float nbr = *((float *)var);
```

> converts void pointer var to an integer/float pointer and then fetches the value stored in that memory address and stores the value in to the variables

instead of

int nbr = (int)var;

float nbr = (float)var;

> converts the address stored in var to int/float. Here you are just converting the address and not the value stored in that address.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to extract arguments from `args` and passing the result to `fct[i]`, pass `args` to `fct[i]` directly and let them do the extraction. The only caveat is that you must not pass by value.

```
    fct[i](&args);
```

In each of the printf* helper functions do something like:

```
void printf_double (va_list *args) {      
   double val = va_arg(*args, double);
   // print it
}
```

Note `float` is not a valid type for `printf` because `float` gets promoted to `double` in varargs calls.